# Image sent to Google Sheets with gspread python appears tiny

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need to send image to google sheets using **gspread**. I am not finding documentation for a function that will work appropriately for it on [docs.gspread.org](https://docs.gspread.org). As shown in my code snippet below, I am currently using the command

```
worksheet.append_row(['testpic.png', '=IMAGE(\"{}\")'.format(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/picturetest/main/download.png')], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

but the picture that gets appended is very tiny and cannot be resized even manually as shown in the attached picture

[image]

I found this guide on google sheets [image] but I wasn't able to get it to work. I tried to implement it like so:

```
worksheet.append_row(['IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", 4, 50, 100)'], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
worksheet.append_row(['IMAGE("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", 4, 50, 100)'])
```

Code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# google scope
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

# read credentials from json
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

# get access using creds
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# open sheet
sheet = client.open("test")

# open worksheet witin sheet
worksheet = sheet.worksheet('check')

# append pic
worksheet.append_row(['testpic.png', '=IMAGE(\"{}\")'.format(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/picturetest/main/download.png')], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

How do I send picture to google sheets and make it scale either to original size or to a set dimension (x,y)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, in order to change the size of image, it is required to change the size of the cell. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```py
worksheet.append_row(['testpic.png', '=IMAGE(\"{}\")'.format(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/picturetest/main/download.png')], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

##### To:

```py
res = worksheet.append_row(['testpic.png', '=IMAGE(\"{}\")'.format(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eliasdon/picturetest/main/download.png')], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')

width = 300 # The cell width. By this, the width of image is changed.
height = 200 # The cell height. By this, the height of image is changed.
row = int(re.findall("\\w+![A-Z]+([0-9]+)", res['updates']['updatedRange'], re.S)[0])
requests = [{
    "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "properties": {
            "pixelSize": height
        },
        "range": {
            "sheetId": worksheet.id,
            "dimension": "ROWS",
            "startIndex": row - 1,
            "endIndex": row
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
    }
},
    {
    "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "properties": {
            "pixelSize": width
        },
        "range": {
            "sheetId": worksheet.id,
            "dimension": "COLUMNS",
            "startIndex": 1,
            "endIndex": 2
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
    }
}
]
spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- In this modification, `import re` is also used.
- When you use this script, the cell size of 2nd column of the appended row is changed.

#### References:

- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)
- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please explain what `row = int(re.findall("\\w+![A-Z]+([0-9]+)", res['updates']['updatedRange'], re.S)[0])` does exactly? I am trying to adapt it my code where the image is the last cell in a row. So my appending command is: `worksheet.append_row([order_id, date, address, 'na', location_name, 'na', 'na', '20', twfrom, twto, 'na', volume, 'na', skills, 'na', 'na', email, phone, 'both',
                          sales_agent, price, appliance, 'na', ' ', '=IMAGE(\"{}\")'.format(
                              image_url)], value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')`

Comment: @Elias Thank you for replying. About `row`, in this case, the row number is retrieved from the returned value from `append_row` method. By this, the batchUpdate method can use the appended row. In your replying, the appended value is different from your question. So please modify the value of `startIndex` and `endIndex` for `COLUMNS` for the column that the image is put. By this, the cell size of the image can be changed.

Comment: I had to use `row = len(list(filter(None, worksheet.col_values(1))))` instead of a regex expression as it was giving an index error. Seems to be working fine now. Thanks again!